# Filtering duplicate items

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to prevent Scrapy from saving to the DB duplicate items. To do so, I used the same strategy shown in the section "Duplicate Filter" from the Scrapy tutorial, which can be found [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).

What I wrote is this:

```
id = str(item['product'] + item['price'])
print id
if id in self.ids_seen:
        raise DropItem("Duplicate item found!")
else:
        self.ids_seen.add(id)
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        log.msg("Entry added to MongoDB database!",
            level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
```

Everything works fine and the duplicates are dropped.

My questions are:

1. Will this be a suitable solution for large sets of data?
2. If the set gets extremely big will the spider get too slow?
3. Is there a better solution to address the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a similar project right now. I'm not sure how long your 
`str(item['product'] + item['price'])` strings are, but for checking against the database, I'm and storing a MD5 hash of all the items I am saving to the db. That way I can quickly create a unique hash of an item and check if it exists against the database. Yes, it does mean storing you are more data, but checking against a db for unique hashes is more efficient than checking long strings.

I'm using pythons's hashlib module for MD5 hashing.

Depending on how large your dataset will be, to avoid collisions you may consider other hashing algorithms like SHA1. I just use MD5 for its speed.

Answer (score 0):

I had once a similar situation where I was dealing with a large set of data. Finally, I decided to check every time if the identifier of the item was already present into the database. Compared to your solution, this one allow you to restart the crawler several times and be sure that you don't have duplicates into your database. Additionally, you could even use it to update your database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question to answer, because it's *very, very much* dependent on your data as well as project goals/needs. This is akin to asking "What dish should supper be served on?"  Don't serve soup on a plate, and don't serve chicken in a teacup.

To directly answer your question:

1. It should be fine at scale, but it does depend on your dataset (what is "product"?  What is "large"?).  If your set gets too big, Python will through a `MemoryError`.
2. With a set, it won't *really* slow down, it will just hit the `MemoryError` and stop working.  Which, is probably worse.
3. If this is a problem, you'll need to use another storage method. A list will allow more items (they are inherently smaller than a set, and thus use less memory), but will take more time to check against.  A database (just for storing "duplicates" for the run is another option).

You'll also have to consider how you define a "duplicate item"? Is any other information stored beyond product/price (and does it matter)?  Do you want to store items in the database already seen on previous crawls?  How large is your expected dataset?

As is, this situation starts to fail with data such as `a = {'product': "Phone", 'price': "29.99"}` and `a = {'product': "Phone2", 'price': "9.99"}`, as both evaluate to `'Phone29.99'`.

You may consider hash, or filtering duplicates on more/less fields.  It should also be noted that this doesn't check the database for duplicates, and already seen items will not persists across calls.